# Which Pokémon can speak with humans?

Tags: pokemon

Inspired by *Detective Pikachu*, I was wondering which Pokémon can "speak" with humans.

I would like to include  Pokémon like Meowth in the anime that speak English/Japanese with their mouths, Pokémon like Mewtwo in the anime/movies that speak telepathically, or other Pokémon we've seen like Lugia/Entei that seem to speak without moving their mouths but still out loud for all to hear (presumably).

The format doesn't matter (manga, anime, video games). And while this is inspired by *Detective Pikachu*, it's not about it, as the movie is not out yet

> And it seems like the human character has the special ability, not the Pikachu

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear, I take it you're looking for Pokémon that can speak *human* languages? Technically speaking, every Pokémon can speak to humans, just not in their language.

Comment: and...tbd if Detective Pikachu is *actually* a Pikachu that can speak to humans (intelligibly @F1Krazy says), or if <spoiler / theory> at play

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not already absolutely clear?

Comment: If you include the Pokémon mystery dungeon series then the answer is every single one of them can talk, except Wobuffet which seems to only be able to say its name and “that’s right!”

Comment: @Laurel I never played those for more than a few minutes! I had no idea!

Answer (score 6):

In the Pokémon anime we have the ability to create human speech with their mouths (as opposed to telepathy, possession, etc):

### Pokémon anime

#### Without any special circumstances

- Team Rocket's Meowth (the vast majority of episodes)
- Gastly (EP020 [*The Ghost of Maiden's Peak*](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP020))
- Chatot (multiple episodes)

  - Repeats human phrases it has heard
- Rotom Pokédex (multiple episodes in *Sun & Moon*)

#### With special circumstances

- Larvitar (EP263 [*Address Unown*](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP263))

  - Only while in the Unown dimension
- Zoroark (BW127 *[The Island of Illusions!](http://The%20Island%20of%20Illusions!)*)

  - Only after transforming itself into Nurse Joy
- Mirror-world Meowth (XY037 *[The Cave of Mirrors!](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/XY037)*)
- Diggersby, Pangoro, Delphox, Froakie, Chesnaught (XY098 *[Dream a Little Dream from Me!](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/XY098)*)

  - While in a dream created by Darkrai

### Films related to the Pokémon anime

- Slowking (*[Pokémon the Movie 2000: The Power of One](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M02)*)
- Entei ([*Pokémon 3: The Movie - Spell of the Unown: Entei*](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M03))

  - In the English dub, an echo filter is added to suggest telepathy, but that doesn't exist in the Japanese version
- Manaphy (*[Pokémon Ranger and the Temple of the Sea](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M09)*)

  - Only able to say simple phrases like "happy" and "I love you"
- Darkrai (*[Pokémon: The Rise of Darkrai](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M10)*)
- Arceus (*[Pokémon: Arceus and the Jewel of Life](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M12)*)
- Hoopa (*[Pokémon the Movie: Hoopa and the Clash of Ages](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M18)*)

And in *[Pokémon the Movie: I Choose You!](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M20)*

> Ash's Pikachu, although possibly through Ash's imagination

In general, any Legendary/Mythical Pokémon in one of these movies will either have human speech or telepathy.

### Pikachu shorts

- Snover (*[Pikachu's Ice Adventure](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/PK19)*, only aired in Japan)

### Video games

- Generation I (Red, Blue, Yellow) and Generation III remakes

  - [Copycat](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Copycat_(character))'s Doduo, which repeats human speech
  - Bill (as hybrid Pokemon)
  - Marowhak's Ghost
- Generation II (Gold, Silver Crystal) and Generation IV remakes

  - Murkrow owned by Team Rocket, which says a password
- Generation IV (Diamond, Pearl, Platinum)

  - Chatot, by imitating human speech through the Chatter move
- Black 2 and White 2

  - Zoroark, disguised as a backpacker
  - Smeargle (Pokéstar Studios "Love and Battle" series)
  - Ledian (Pokéstar Studios "Timegate Traveler" series)
- Generation VII (Sun, Moon, Ultra Sun, Ultra Moon)

  - Rotom (when inside the Rotom Pokédex)
  - Mimikyu
  - Oranguru (says "Go du it!")
- Detective Pikachu

  - The titular Detective Pikachu

---

Source: [Talking Pokémon](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Talking_Pok%C3%A9mon)

Answer (score 4):

The only Pokemon I know of which can speak human speech are:

- Meowth
- Ghastly
- Slowking
- Entei
- Darkai
- Arceus
- Snowver
- Hoopa
- Lucario
- and the Rotom Pokedex

**All of my information was from** https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Talking_Pok%C3%A9mon

Comment: To be clear: "human speech" in this context means "moving your mouth to produce sounds in a human language", not telepathy.

Comment: The question was about communicating intelligibly per conceptual language, thus including Mewtwo. Therefore, it seems to be a partial answer (and a good start). I think it's funny that Team Rocket's Meowth is not included, so it is not even including all *talking* individuals.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Sadly, the original poster seems to have left, so we won't get clarification on whether telepathy is okay.

Comment: @Thunderforge: Well, it is part of the unedited, original body of the question that telepathy should be included, so I think we do not need a message out of the digital tomb for clarification in this case.